# Almost finished with my first Android application made with Ice Cream Sandwich and was wondering about backwards comptibility

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, backwards-compatibility, android-2.3-gingerbread

Hello I have developed my first application for Android using the Ice Cream Sandwich SDK and I was wondering if there was a way to make this compatible for devices also running Gingerbread without having to re-do the entire program.  I have tried to find the answer to this from other sources but haven't found anything yet.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: That depends entirely on whether or not you used Honeycomb and ICS specific APIs throughout the entire program.  An easy way to check would be to set the minimum target API to 2.3 and run LINT.  The warnings will tell you which APIs won't run on 2.3.

Comment: In addition to setting a target API as already suggested, take a look at the [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to add support for some features added in later versions, such as Fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations for the development of your first application ;)
It's difficult to answer to your questions without knowing what your application is using. If your application use new features of the Android ICS API, you have to implements some compatibility code (see [Support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)). If not, you just need to add this in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
/>
```

Note that 7 is for Android 2.1

The best way to know if you use specific API of Android 4 (ICS) is to try to launch your project on an emulator under a lower version. If this give you error(s), it's because you have compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your `build target` in Eclipse to `Android 2.3`. If you get any compilation errors in Eclipse, than this means that you are using `APIs` that are not available in `2.3` and your application will crash when it is going to reach at those lines when running on `2.3`> .

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure youre using APIs that are there on older versions of Android. Try to read the wahts new for ICS and avoid those :) which pretty much beats the purpose of using a newer SDK that changes alot and breaks lots of things. Beware of the new layouts....